# Nested list: Finding largest value?

Tags: python

How do you search the list for the highest value and output which str(ie. str1, str2, etc) has the highest value in their respective sub-list?
My desired output is: Highest value is: str5: 5

```
# list containing string variables in each sublist
list = [["str1"], ["str2"], ["str3"], ["str4"], ["str5"]]

    # Go through the list
    for i in list:
        while True:
            try:
                val = float(input(f"Enter {i[0]}'s value:"))
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter float")
            else:
                i.append(val)
                break
    
    print(list)

    output:

    Enter str1's value:1
    Enter str2's value:2
    Enter str3's value:3
    Enter str4's value:4
    Enter str5's value:5
    [['str1', 1.0], ['str2', 2.0], ['str3', 3.0], ['str4', 4.0], ['str5', 5.0]]
```

Comment: Don't use inbuilt type names (`list`) for your variable names. You will cause yourself all sorts of problems...

Comment: You could use a dictionary too, it would be a lot more "pythonic" to search for a max value

Comment: Umm. What does the code have to do with the question you're nominally asking?

Comment: @MadPhysicist what are you talking about?

Comment: @olirwin  I'm opting for a list because that is were I'm at in my book and I want to get this down first.

Comment: @Nick Sure I got it

Comment: You ask how to find the largest value, but you show no attempt to do so. Your list making code can and should be reduced to a single direct assignment

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have pseudo code and do you have any ideas for reducing the single direct assignment? What is it called so I can look it up

Answer (score 0):

Well concerning this particular example you could use the following code .

```
max = 0 // zero is always smaller than a max value
maxSublist = [] //define an empty array to store the sublist that is has the max value
for sublist in list:   // iterate your list
    if float(sublist[1])> max: // if value of list greater than max
        max = float(sublist[1]) // makes it the new max so it thresholds later iterations
        maxSublist = sublist // store the max sublist so far to the value
print(maxSublist) // when you are done print it
```

Hoped I helped you out, feel free to ask any further questions.